# c language void function returning same result

Tags: c, void

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void squeeze(char s[], int c);

int main(){

    char x[]="cats";
    int y =10;

    squeeze(x,y);

    printf("%s %d\n", x, y);
    return 0;
}


void squeeze (char s[], int c){
    int i,j;
    for(i = j=0; s[i]!='\0'; i++)
        if(s[i] !=c)
            s[j++]=s[i];
    s[j] = '\0';
}
```

This function is "delete all c from s".  I don't how to make it work. The output of this function is `cats, 10`, nothing changes.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Since the string `cats` does not contain character `10`, you should not expect a change, should you?  In code sets derived from ASCII, character `10` is the newline `'\n'` character.  Create a string `char z[] = "One\nline\nor\nmany\n";` and call `squeeze(z, '\n');`, printing `z` before and after.

Comment: got it. thank you forgot about the ascii.

Answer (score 2):

The function works correctly.

The problem is that the string `cats` does not contain character `10`, so you should not expect a change.  In codesets derived from ASCII, character `10` is the newline `'\n'` character.  Create a string `char z[] = "One\nline\nor\nmany\n";` and call `sqeeze(z, '\n');`, printing `z` before and after:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void squeeze(char s[], int c);

int main(void)
{
    char x[] = "cats";
    int y = 10;

    printf("before: [%s] %d\n", x, y);
    squeeze(x, y);
    printf("after:  [%s] %d\n", x, y);

    printf("%s %d\n", x, y);
    char z[] = "One\nline\nor\nmany\n";
    printf("before: [%s]\n", z);
    squeeze(z, '\n');

    printf("after:  [%s]\n", z);
    return 0;
}

void squeeze(char s[], int c)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = j = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
        if (s[i] != c)
            s[j++] = s[i];

    s[j] = '\0';
}
```

The output from that is:

```
before: [cats] 10
after:  [cats] 10
cats 10
before: [One
line
or
many
]
after:  [Onelineormany]
```